# Regex match cookie value and remove hyphens

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cookies, match

I'm trying to extract out a group of words from a larger string/cookie that are separated by hyphens.  I would like to replace the hyphens with a space and set to a variable.  Javascript or jQuery.

As an example, the larger string has a name and value like this within it:

```
facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store;
```

(notice the leading "C")

So first, I need to match()/find facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store; with regex.  Then break it down to `"Conner Department Store"`

var cookie = document.cookie;
var facilityValue = cookie.match( REGEX );  ??

Comment: how would you seperate `C` & `Conner`?!

Comment: ^ also is the above string representative of every case you are trying to solve (can it be assumed that you are always looking for the value from after `%7C` to end of line)

Comment: @chsdk `%7C` is a URL encoded pipe, no need to differentiate, just need to url decode

Comment: I'm thinking you could disallow two consecutive Uppercase letters in the regex.. just a thought though.

Comment: Just decode the string at first with `decodeURIComponent(string)` which returns the following: `"facility=34222|Conner-Department-Store;"` then you can modify the string however you want. E.g. apply substring(...) or split('|')

Comment: @Mike disallowing two consecutive Uppcercase letters is totally unneccessary, the `%7C` just represents `|` encoded

Comment: Did you actually mean to change `Conner` to `Connor` or is that a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var test = "store=874635%7Csomethingelse;facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store;store=874635%7Csomethingelse;";

var test2 = test.replace(/^(.*)facility=([^;]+)(.*)$/, function(matchedString, match1, match2, match3){
    return decodeURIComponent(match2);
});

console.log( test2 );
console.log( test2.split('|')[1].replace(/[-]/g, ' ') );
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you technically kept the semicolon.

Comment: I need to first extract facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store; from a larger string/cookie

Comment: @Mike see my answer. You didn't specifically ask for cookie extraction in your question though.

Comment: @LincolnBergeson  Sorry, I will update the question.  Don't want to use a third party addon for this, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Mike it's a ~50 line file, you can just copy their code without the framework.

Comment: @Mike updated the answer to find the facility in the string.

Comment: Why don't you just set `test2` directly by using `return decodeURIComponent(match2);` from the replace function? `var test2 = test.replace(...);`

Comment: Good stuff @Taplar   Thank you!  Thanks also RyanWheale for the refinement.

Comment: Are you saying that you have some key=value1SEPARATORvalue2 where the SEPARATOR is not an encoded `|` ? @Mike

Comment: Right, because the assumption is that the string is encoded, thus the decodeURIComponent part to convert the encoded characters back to normal characters for processing; and from your example the expectation was that this separator was going to be the `|` character encoded.  If it's not you'd have to figure out what %7F decodes to and add that to the split call, or otherwise figure out why you are using multiple characters as separators and consider using only one for simplicity.  `2%7Conner-` would remove the C because the C is apart of the character encoding in that example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it correctly, you want to make a phrase by getting all the words between hyphens and disallowing two successive Uppercase letters in a word, so I'd prefer using Regex in that case.

This is a Regex solution, that works dynamically with any cookies in the same format and extract the wanted sentence from it:

```
var matches = str.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+)-?/g);
console.log(matches.map(function(m) {
  return m.replace('-', '');
}).join(" "));
```

**Demo:**

```js
var str = "facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store;";

var matches = str.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+)-?/g);
console.log(matches.map(function(m) {
  return m.replace('-', '');
}).join(" "));
```

**Explanation:**

- Use this Regex `(/([A-Z][a-z]+)-?/g` to match the words between `-`.
- Replace any `-` occurence in the matched words.
- Then just join these matches array with white space.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
first, you should decode this string as follows:

```
var str = "facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store;"
var decoded = decodeURIComponent(str);
// decoded = "facility=34222|Conner-Department-Store;"
```

Then you have multiple possibilities to split up this string.
The easiest way is to use `substring()`

`var solution1 = decoded.substring(decoded.indexOf('|') + 1, decoded.length)
// solution1 = "Conner-Department-Store;"
solution1 = solution1.replace('-', ' ');
// solution1 = "Conner Department Store;"`

As you can see, `substring(arg1, arg2)` returns the string, starting at index `arg1` and ending at index `arg2`. See Full Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

If you want to cut the last `;` just set `decoded.length - 1` as `arg2` in the snippet above.

```
decoded.substring(decoded.indexOf('|') + 1, decoded.length - 1)
//returns "Conner-Department-Store"
```

- or all above in just one line:

`decoded.substring(decoded.indexOf('|') + 1, decoded.length - 1).replace('-', ' ')`

If you want still to use a regular Expression to retrieve (perhaps more) data out of the string, you could use something similar to this snippet:

```
var solution2 = "";
var regEx= /([A-Za-z]*)=([0-9]*)\|(\S[^:\/?#\[\]\@\;\,']*)/;
if (regEx.test(decoded)) {
solution2 = decoded.match(regEx);
    /* returns 
    [0:"facility=34222|Conner-Department-Store",
    1:"facility",
    2:"34222",
    3:"Conner-Department-Store",
    index:0,
    input:"facility=34222|Conner-Department-Store;"
    length:4] */
solution2 = solution2[3].replace('-', ' ');
// "Conner Department Store"
}
```

I have applied some rules for the regex to work, feel free to modify them according your needs. 
`facility` can be any Word built with alphabetical characters lower and uppercase (no other chars) at any length
`=` needs to be the char `=`
`34222` can be any number but no other characters
`|` needs to be the char `|`
`Conner-Department-Store` can be any characters except one of the following (reserved delimiters): `:/?#[]@;,'`

Hope this helps :)

> edit:  to find only the part
>   `facility=34222%7CConner-Department-Store;` just modify the regex to
>   match `facility=` instead of `([A-z]*)=`:
>   `/(facility)=([0-9]*)\|(\S[^:\/?#\[\]\@\;\,']*)/`

Answer (score -1):

You can use [cookies.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework), a mini framework from MDN (Mozilla Developer Network).

Simply include the cookies.js file in your application, and write:

`docCookies.getItem("Connor Department Store");`

Comment: OPs question isn't about getting cookies, it's about getting the value and parsing it

Comment: @CarlMarkham OP left a comment saying he needed it.